# How to create a ManyToManyField with choices

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a Django (1.7.3) `models.ManyToManyField` which allows the user to select multiple options form a `MultipleChoiceField` but I am having a little trouble. The idea is that the user can select multiple elections they intend to vote in.

Currently when I run syncdb I get no errors and when I visit the page with the question it is only partially displayed with a default title and no question options.

[image]

I have been looking around online and here on SO but I am not sure what I am missing. Any help is much appriciated

**models.py**

```
class Person(models.Model):

    election = models.ManyToManyField('Elections')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self


class Elections(models.Model):

    ELECTION_TYPE = (
        ('NONE', 'None'),
        ('LOCAL', 'Local elections'),
        ('STATE', 'State elections e.g. Governorship'),
        ('NATIONAL', 'National elections e.g. Congress and Senate'),
        ('PRESIDENTIAL', 'Presidential elections'),
        ('OTHER', 'Other'),
        ('DONT_KNOW', "Don't know"),)  

    election_type = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100, default=None, choices=ELECTION_TYPE, verbose_name = 'Which elections do you regularly vote in or intend to vote in? Select all that apply.')


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self
```

**forms.py**

```
class SurveyFormD(forms.ModelForm): # Political Viewpoints

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['liberal_conservative', 'democrat_republican', 'voting_rights', 'elections']        

        widgets = {'liberal_conservative' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'democrat_republican' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'voting_rights' : forms.RadioSelect,
                   'elections' : forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,}
```

Comment: show template and view.

Comment: The template and view would have no effect on this. The template is the standard SessionWizardView template and everything uses {{ form }}. The view is also very simular to the standard with some cusomisation on the later pages of the form https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/